# ¿Como autorizar el acceso a Google Drive con OAuth2?

Tags: java, api, oauth, google-drive, google-oauth

En mi proyecto de fin de carrera quiero implementar un cliente en el cual con tu cuenta de Google Drive se sincronicen ciertos archivos.

Estoy intentando usar la API de Google Drive para Java y estoy bastante perdido con el OAuth2 porque todas las fuentes que leo indican que hay que acreditar la aplicación en Google Developers para que pueda acceder a Drive.

Lo que necesito es que cada persona que use la aplicación se conecte a su cuenta de Google para usar sus directorios de Drive.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con el tema de la autorización con OAuth2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, necesitas crear un proyecto en la consola de google.

Después generar las credenciales que usaras en tu código y que solo tu debes conocer, estas van a permitir que tu aplicación arroje el dialogo pidiendo permiso para ciertos datos (scope) del usuario como **Google +**, **Google Docs** o **Google Drive** en este caso.

Te dejo un [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004163448/http://www.moisesbelda.com:80/tutorial-acceso-google-oauth2-api/) muy bueno para crear tu proyecto y las credenciales necesarias en google desde cero.

Una ves teniendo el acceso es cuestión de trabajar con las [APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/) de drive para ver o manipular los archivos del usuario actual.

Comment: Gracias por responder. El problema es que en mi caso esta aplicación sería orientada a un usuario cualquiera, no sólo a mi como desarrollador, por tanto mi duda es si es estrictamente necesario hacer lo del Oauth (que entiendo que sí) o si es posible hacer todos los pasos por comandos en java de manera que el usuario sólo introduce su email y contraseña y el programa lo abstrae de hacer todos estos pasos engorrosos.

Gracias.

Comment: Vale, ya me he aclarado viendo más profundamente el funcionamiento de Oauth2 y ya lo tengo funcionando. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo, si te sirvió mi información podrías seleccionar mi respuesta como la buena. :D

Comment: como va? podrías explicarme como hiciste el funcionamiento ya que yo estoy en la misma duda ahora mismo muchas gracias saludos.