# Archivo compartido usando Google Drive API el acceso esta restringido

Tags: api, google-drive

estoy usando el Google drive API para que los usuarios puedan compartir sus archivos pero cuando lo suben y el archivo lo intentan abrir sale que el acceso estar restringido y que hay que pedir acceso. Como se pudiera subir el URL publico para poder abrir el archivo de solo lectura.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que los archivos están siendo subidos con si tú mismo los hubieras subido. Para que se suban con como si los hubieran subido cada usuario de tu aplicación deberás usar OAuth.

Revisa [Concepts > Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) (me parece que no está disponible en español.

Relacionado

- [¿Como autorizar el acceso a Google Drive con OAuth2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4246/65)